# How to resize column width in table with selenium driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, browser-automation

I am automating some website tests by Selenium, one step needs to resize the column width (reduce the column width) of tables, (the table looks like excel table as example).

How could I automate it?

From stackoverflow, for similar questions, some one advised to use Action e.g

```
action.clickAndHold(elementToResize).moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset).release()
```

But, how to locate the element to resize by css (The element to resize is the edge of column) if I use mouse in UI?

Or should I use executeScript? If so, anyone could give me one example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code trials please

Comment: please share your html code ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example for using Actions in selenium 3.0 to resize.

```
package testActionsJquery;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class testResizable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Chetan\\Desktop\\Chetan\\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resizable/");

        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        //Get xpath using firebug.
        WebElement resize = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='resizable']/div[3]"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        Thread.sleep(3000L);
        //Using appropriate x and y axis coordinates
        action.dragAndDropBy(resize, 400, 200).perform();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Action class in Selenium Webdriver.

For example

1. Get the width and height of Element using `WebElement.getSize().getWidth()` & `.getHeight()`.
2. Use the `Actions.moveToElement(toElement, full_width, half_height)` to move the mouse to the right-middle edge of the Element.
3. Use `.clickAndHold()` & `.moveByOffset(offset_to_move, 0)` & `.release()` to resize.

Replace resizeable element in the below example with the table header `th` element to resize a table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //To open chrome browser.
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Windows\\System32\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //To wait until the element get visible or invisible.
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
    driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/resizable/default.html");  
    //For wait until the element get visible.
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("resizable")));
    WebElement resize_div = driver.findElement(By.id("resizable"));
    //Get Width * Height of Element
    int divWidth = resize_div.getSize().getWidth();
    int divHeight = resize_div.getSize().getHeight();
    System.out.println("Actual width: " + divWidth);
    //Get half of Height
    int halfHeight = divHeight/2;
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action resizable = builder
            .moveToElement(resize_div, divWidth, halfHeight)
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(divWidth, 0)
            .release()
            .build();

    resizable.perform();
  //Get Width of Element
    divWidth = resize_div.getSize().getWidth();
    System.out.println("Final width: " + divWidth);

}
```